# Fitting a model while adjusting for some variable

Tags: regression, time-series, model

I plan to figure out the effect of variable X on variable Y. I have time series data for both X and Y and a simple regression model should do the job. Unfortunately the variable Y is also affected by variable A and B (both are time series).

What I want to inquire is how can I find the exact effect of X on Y while adjusting for the effects of A and B. Will a simple regression model Y ~ X + A + B + intercept do the job?

For simplicity, let's assume that X and Y have a linear relationship.

Comment: Check the residual diagnostics after estimating the model. If you find a pattern like autocorrelation, you should consider some time series model like ARIMA. Then X, A and B could be included as exogenous regressors. If they are not supposed to be exogenous, you could try a VAR model.

Comment: so in simple terms , if X and A and B are independent of each other than a simple linear regression will do the job. Right?

Comment: No. If X, A and B are independent of Y then you can try a simple linear regression. Even then you should check the residuals, and quite likely they will not be nice looking so you will have to go for a time series model.

Comment: Is it mandatory to concider the lag terms of Y? 

Also I am not sure how can I include external variables in autoregressive models. I mean arent autoregressive models only designed when using the lag terms of the response variable?

Comment: I would not say it is mandatory but it makes sense if a model without lags does not pass diagnostic tests. The simplest ARIMA model has no exogenous regressors, but ARIMAX does. `arima` function in `R` allows for that using argument `xreg`. A good explanation of how that works is given by Rob J. Hyndman in his [blog](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/).

Comment: So a model Y(t) ~ X(t) + A(t) + B(t) + Y(t-1)... + Y(t-q) + c  will help me figure out the effect of X on Y (adjusted for all external variables) ... for ease lets assume that only A and B are external variables...

Comment: Yes. Although *external* is perhaps not the proper term in this context; *exogenous* is better defined.